# UICollectionView cell disappears when i scroll it

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView whose scroll direction is horizontal. It has only one line and its cell spacing is 16.0px. So i set its `collectionViewLayout` to a custom layout named `UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout` subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout *layout     = [[UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection                        = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing                = 16.0;
_myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout        = layout;  
_myCollectionView.autoresizingMask            = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

But when i scroll the collectionView, some cells of it disappeared. So weird! I have tried every solution i can find from `google.com`, unfortunately did not work for me. I fix it and post the solution as a answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it !

I replace the custom `UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout` with native `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` just like this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout     = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
_myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
_myCollectionView.autoresizingMask     = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And I set the cell spacing through storyboard（also you can set them through the layout's propery）:
[image: cell spacing]

Then i run the project again , the UICollectionViewCell DO NOT DISAPPEAR anymore.